# [CapNProto][pycapnp] Struct Send Server

Tags: python, struct, sendmessage, python-sockets, capnproto

How do I send a server a struct?

I tried:

```
import socket
import sys
import capnp
import select
import test_capnp

class Test:
    def __init__(self, serverAddr="127.0.0.1", serverPort = 10000):
        self.serverAddress = (serverAddr, serverPort)
        capnp.remove_import_hook()
        self.setupClient()

    def setupClient(self):
        _socket = socket.socket()
        _socket.connect(self.serverAddress)
        client = capnp.TwoPartyClient(_socket)
        send = client.bootstrap().cast_as(capnp._DynamicCapabilityClient(test_capnp))
```

Test.capnp:

```
struct Test {
     id @0 : UInt8;
     msg @1 : Text;
}
```

Furthermore, how can I give values ​​to the Test?
Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score -1):

lol have you proceed to the second turn of the competition?

Comment: This should not be an answer rather than a comment.